# Why there is different versions of Python on Atom IDE console and in terminal?

Tags: python, web, version, conda

I'm new to Python and in web dev and now I'am learning to code with Django. I'm using Atom IDE and I installed Anaconda with Python version 3.8.2.

But when I activate VirtualEnvironment and type Atom console "python" and see that the installed version of python is 2.7.16.

[image]

When I use terminal and do the same thing I see that python version is 3.8.2 as expected.

[image]

If I type in Atom "Python3" I see 3.7.3 version for some reason.

[image]

Why in Atom I see such old version of Python? 
And why if I type python3 I see version lower than I installed and why in the terminal I see what I expect but not i Atom?

Thank you!

Comment: Virtual Environments allows for different versions of Python because some applications/libraries may use different versions of Python as well. This allows for people to work with different versions in different environments and some python code/libraries may not be updated to use the latest versions of Python.

All/most IDEs allow for setting the Python version that will run in that specific environment.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But how I can set default version? I've tried to set default in script folder preferences but result is the same (python -> 2.7.16). Basically I installed anaconda and I manage to do default version of python to 3.8.2 but this time I've made the same steps but result is different.